# how to obtain a servlet instance in a Guice/Inject/GuiceFilter servlet environment?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt

I'd like to test my gwt client using the gwt-test-utils library (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/). While the standard implementation already delivers a `GwtCreateHandler` (used to mimic `GWT.create` on `RemoteService`) that handles / mappings, it does nothing to handle the Guice servlet extension (`GuiceFilter` / `GuiceServletContextListener`).

Basically I need to find the servlet, or the servlet class that handles a specific url, that I know:

```
String url = ... // I know this.
// I know everything else (Injector, GuiceServletContextListener, etc).
Class<?> servletClazz = ... // How to get this?
```

Is this even possible?
Of course, running a `GWTTestCase` would work, but:

1. it is too slow
2. `gwt-test-utils` is pure java, so I don't see why it would not be possible

Thanks, 
Alex D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Tadedon](http://code.google.com/p/tadedon/):

> - Bind application configuration in Guice module.
> - Support @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations (JSR 250) in
>     Guice    application. incject slf4j loggers.
> - annotate your methods with @Transactional annotation.
> - Support guice stage in your web application.
> - [test your guice managed servlets and filters](http://code.google.com/p/tadedon/wiki/GuiceServletMockModule) without need of real
>     servlet container.
> - use guice Matchers for matching super class, interface and type
>     literal annotations

Comment: that's great, however the project lacks a jar download / ant build ... I'll have to do that manually :). Thanks again